# CP2013SP1 Import Fails to read IF Package

Tags: 2013, content-porter-2013

We have SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1, CP 2013 SP1, Windows 2012 R2 Server ( here Running the CP client , first installed via the IE...)

```
Error = "File Path/TESTOneItem.zip is not a package or package file is corrupted.
```

[image: CP Import Error screen]

1. We had CMS up and running for a while 2013sp1 HR1. All works.
2. Installed the CP client and exported from DEV into IF format (zip)
3. While trying to IMPORT the IF package into TEST environment CP gave
   error that Package is corrupted

Any idea why CP doesnt like the IF package? The same package works on CP on another instance(not part of this env )

Much appreciated for your positive response.

Thanks Vin

Comment: did you check the CP logs?

Comment: Is destination CM where you are trying to import also 2013 sp1 hr1 or some other version?

Comment: Can you apply the reverse test as well? So verify that this CM can import ANY package (other than this one ofc.)?

Comment: It might also be that you copied the zip file from server A to server B and the server B has blocked it. Right-click the ZIP, get the properties and check whether that is the case.

Comment: @Rai, it wasnt the lockign across server issue. It was with the VC++ version issue. Across server all works fine after correcting it. More details added in my below response.

Answer (score 9):

Have manged to resolve the issue

1. The CMS server(x64bit) had `Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 Redistributable - 10.0.40219` Installed
2. For CP 2013SP1 it needs `Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86` else CP on the server gives above noted error.

After installing the VC++ x86 it works like a charm. Sharing here for the rest of the CP lovers :)

Thanks
Vin

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=5555

You can download the VC++ 2010 x86 version from above link

Answer (score 2):

The only issues I have seen with imports not working (in my case the import actually did succeed, but it corrupted some of the imported multimedia Components) was due to a temp file corruption. After clearing the temporary files in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\ImportExport\Temp`, running the import again worked for me.

It seemed to be bound to only one server which maybe had some bad spots on its harddrive. It happened a few times on that server but everytime deleting the temp files was the solution.

Another possibility I can think of is that your zip file might have been corrupted on upload of the server. In that case it should work fine when you use Content Porter from a different location, preferably from the original location or the one where the import did work on another environment.