# Content Porter 2013 SP1 Import fails to read IF Package

Tags: content-porter-2013

Using

- SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1
- Content Porter Client 2013 SP1
- Windows 2012 R2 Server (here Running the CP client , first installed via the IE...)

Error message `File Path/TESTOneItem.zip is not a package or package file is corrupted.`

[image: error message screenshot]

1. We had CMS up and running for a while 2013sp1 HR1. All works.
2. Installed the CP client and exported from DEV into IF format (zip)
3. While trying to IMPORT the IF package into TEST environment CP gave error that Package is corrupted.

Any idea why CP doesnt like the IF package?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CP2013SP1 Import Fails to read IF Package](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11980/cp2013sp1-import-fails-to-read-if-package)

Comment: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11980/cp2013sp1-import-fails-to-read-if-package  is a duplicate of this question, it was created 15 minutes after.

Comment: THis was by mistake created at incorrect stack(which was copied after couple of days).  Took 15mins to realize then created in the right location  http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11980/cp2013sp1-import-fails-to-read-if-package?noredirect=1#comment14881_11980

Comment: Based on timing I think this should be left open and the other qestion would be the duplicate/double post. I know in 2012 we talked about being more active on StackOverflow, but it's good to remember we have a _Tridion_ Stack Exchange now.

Comment: The other question has more upvotes and the appropriate answer by Vinod himself hence I would reverse the duplicate vote and close...

Answer (score 2):

The cause of this error is a missing perequisite. The Content Porter client has a prerequisite on **Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86**. Make sure this is installed, and that this 32 bit is version is installed.

Content Porter Client will not work with the 64 bit version. The 32 bit version and 64 bit version of Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 can co-exist, so no need to uninstall the 64 bit version if you are running a 64 bit machine.

Comment: Indeed. You can also read this thread    http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11980/cp2013sp1-import-fails-to-read-if-package